# Use Material UI styled for MUI X datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, mui-x

I wanted to customize the date picker and tried to remove the padding from the input in the MUI X date picker but nothing was working.
Am I doing something wrong here or is styled not supported by MUI X?

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { DesktopDatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';


const DateDisplay = styled(DesktopDatePicker)(({ theme }) => ({
  '& input':{
   padding: 0,
},
}));


  return (
    <ModalDialog>
      <div>
        
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
          <DateDisplay
            value={new Date()}
            readOnly
            onChange={() => {}}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          ></DateDisplay>
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </div>
    </ModalDialog>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sx={{}}` prop.

```
<DateDisplay
   value={new Date()}
   readOnly
   onChange={() => {}}
   renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField 
         {...params} 
         sx={{
            '.MuiInputBase-input': {padding: 0},
         }}
      />
   )}
></DateDisplay>
```

With '.MuiInputBase-input' class, you can customize your `<TextField>` render input for your DatePicker.

Comment: I have tried you proposed solution, however none of them work for me, do you have a sample working code?